# how to show search results inside existed list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a tracklist that I fetched from API
I implement search bar that is responsible for looking for according track
But the problem is that when I input anything in search bar, another tracklist appears and it's filtered same way I wanted to filter already existed tracklist with the name of track and artist.
I thougt I need to use map in map method.

```
const TrackList = ({trackList}) => {

 const [searchTerm, setSerchTerm] = useState('')
 const [searchRes, setSearchRes] = useState([])

 const settingSearch = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()
    setSerchTerm(e.target.value)
 }
 useEffect(() => {
        const res = trackList.map(i=> {
            return i.name
        })
        const filteredRes = res.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
        setSearchRes(filteredRes)
        
 }, [searchTerm])

    return (
        <div>
           <Container>
              <h1 className='mb-5 mt-5'>Top TrackList</h1>

              <FormControl type="text" 
                         placeholder="Search" 
                         className="mr-sm-2" 
                        value={searchTerm}
                        onChange={settingSearch}
                         
                         />
                           <ul>
                             { searchRes.map(i => (
                               <li>{i}</li>

                           )) }
                             </ul>
                   
                          
                {trackList.map(item => {
                    return (
                        
                        <Row className='mt-1' style={{padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #000', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Col lg={1} md={1} sm={1}>
                        <a href={item.artist.url}><img src={item.image[1]['#text']} /></a>
                            
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg={11} md={11} sm={11}>
                         
                        <Link to={`/artist/${item.artist.name}`}><h6>{item.artist.name}</h6></Link>
                        <p>"{item.name}"</p>
                        </Col>
                        </Row>
                       

                    )
                })}
                         
          </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you `map` over both `trackList` and `searchRes`.

You may want to set `searchRes` equal to the array in `trackList` when the page renders like this

```
 const [searchRes, setSearchRes] = useState(trackList)
```

And then use it in your map like this

```
{searchRes.map(item => {
    return (<Row className='mt-1' style={{padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #000', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
...
```

And remove this

```
<ul>
    { searchRes.map(i => (
        <li>{i}</li>

    )) }
</ul>
```

Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: if I do this way, so as soon as I run this app I can see only search bar and when I enter data nothing filters. But first I need to see track list and search above and as I enter any data, filtered result have to stay and the rest disappear.

Comment: See my updated answer (I changed the first code block to remove the `useEffect`), let me knoe if it works now.

Comment: The idea is to assign the full value of `trackList` to `searchRes` right in the beginning and use `searchRes` to display first all tracks and then once you filter only show the filtered ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you dont need useeffect just set filtered array onchange input and add next time pls all files what you use like Container, FormControl i dont know exactly what each of it is and it hard to check is it correct

```js
const TrackList = ({trackList}) => {
  const [searchRes, setSearchRes] = useState(trackList);

  const settingSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const filteredRes = trackList.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value));
    setSearchRes(filteredRes)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <h1 className='mb-5 mt-5'>Top TrackList</h1>
        <FormControl type="text"
                     placeholder="Search"
                     className="mr-sm-2"
                     onChange={settingSearch}
        />
        {searchRes.map(item => (
          <Row className='mt-1' style={{padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #000', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Col lg={1} md={1} sm={1}>
              <a href={item.artist.url}><img src={item?.image?.[1]['#text']} /></a>
            </Col>
            <Col lg={11} md={11} sm={11}>
              <Link to={`/artist/${item.artist.name}`}><h6>{item.artist.name}</h6></Link>
              <p>{item.name}</p>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
};
```